# Which are the popular bot frameworks for developing chatbot for website or web application?

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot

I am looking to create a chatbot for my web application, I have tried the Microsoft Bot Framework but I am unable to customise chat screen and copy text for the chat screen using both Direct Line and WebChat. So I am looking for options which can provide me more options for customisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webchat control is an open source project you can download and customize.  You should be able to edit the scss.  The repo can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/src). This is your best option unless you would like to write your own control from scratch.  I'm not aware of another framework that has an embeddable control such as webchat.